# Referencing other movieclips within actionscript class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3, movieclip

I have externalized the actionscript code of a movieclip into a separate class files.
This movieclip requires references to some other clips on the stage. What I am currently doing to reference those clips is by using Movieclip(this.parent).otherclip but somehow that feels wrong.

Is there a better way to pass in the required references into a class extending from Movieclip inside of the constructor? Or what is the recommended pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the parent movie clip have a class as well ?
If, maybe the **parent class** should **manage initializing** it's **children**.

If not, you could **dispatch an event** from the class your are writing, and listen for that event in the parent.

If it's something complex and performance is an issue, you could just **add function callbacks**.

HTH,
George

Comment: Hi George, the parent is actually just the stage. The movieClips are all on the stage. It's a zoom-slider which communicates with the actual timeline. I like the idea to do things event driven.

For function callbacks timeline and zoom slider need to still somehow know each, no? Which would again boil down to establishing a reference through parent.otherClip.

Comment: Is the class you externalized the Slider ? If so, from a level up, your main timeline, you should listen for the change event from the slider and control the timeline from there. I don't think I fully understand your setup though. Also, if it helps, I wrote a little extension that declares instances for you so you can use them in an externalized class for example: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1860528. Could you post a snippet or explain your setup a bit more in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

try `(parent as Object)` anyway the dispatch event approach is much better.